# Laravel localization: optional placeholders

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, localization, laravel-5.1

In [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/localization), you can use placeholders in localization files, so that if you have a `welcome.php` file set up with the following rule:

`'welcome' => 'Welcome, :name. Everything alright in :city?',`

and you use this to print out a message:

`echo trans('messages.welcome', ['name' => 'Dayle', 'city' => 'Boston']);`

you will see this:

`Hello, Dayle! Everything alright in Boston?`

Here `:name` is a placeholder. My question is: can you make these placeholders optional, i.e. if their value is `null`, a different text will be displayed? In the above case, if we skipped the `city` argument in the `trans` function, I would like to see this:

`Hello, Dayle!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the `trans_choice` function as a switch statement?

```
echo trans_choice('messages.welcome', intval(isset($city)))
```

You could then use the translation file like so:

```
'welcome' => '{0} Welcome :name! | {1} Welcome :name ! Everything alright in :city?'
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that as for Laravel 5.6+ the `|` must be without spaces around

So it would work as
`'welcome' => '{0} Welcome :name!|{1} Welcome :name ! Everything alright in :city?'`

Also for future reades you must send `$name` and `$city` inside `trans_choice`
like this `echo trans_choice('messages.welcome', intval(isset($city)), ["name" => $name, "city" => $city])`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something another logic, creating multiple trans. So:

```
'welcome' => 'Welcome, :name. Everything alright in :city?',
'welcome2' => 'Welcome, :name',

if(is_null($city){
   echo trans('messages.welcome2', ['name' => 'Dayle']);
}
else{
   echo trans('messages.welcome', ['name' => 'Dayle', 'city' => 'Boston']);
}
```

Comment: i know this is an option but in my case i have three variables, so i would like to avoid complicated constructions like this one, hence the question.

Comment: Trans does not support any logic inside the text using `isset` or `is_null`. Also, from my experience, I can say you, your way is more complicated than I provide.